# Is it Possible to Dynamically Create Input Fields from ModelMetaData.Properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

I am iterating around `ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties` to render some inputs for these properties:

```
@foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties
                .Where(p => (p.AdditionalValues.Count > 0) && ((bool)p.AdditionalValues["tags"])))
{
    // Generate form here
}
```

I am able to display the `LabelFor` correctly with

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => Model, 
    property.DisplayName, 
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

But I can't seem to get the editor working.

I tried

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GetType().GetProperties().First(t=>t.Name == property.PropertyName))
```

But I am seeing this error:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

I also tried

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => property)
```

But then the value comes through as `null` to the controller

is it possible to do this, or will I need to code each input manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with:

```
<input class="form-control" id="@($"{property.PropertyName}Field")"
       name="@property.PropertyName" type="hidden" value="" />
```

And the value now pulls through to the controller.

I guess all it needs is the `name` attribute to match the property name of the `ViewModel`